# How to mock method used with the class declared inside free function?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I want to mock method set in class Man.
How to make it with gmock? 
This is how I try. What is wrong?

```
bool Man::set(uint8_t val)
{
//not important, let it be
 print("aaa");
}


bool alfa(bool a)
{
    Man m;
    m.set(a == true ? 1 : 0);

    return true;
}

class MockMan : public Man {
 public:
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, set, (uint8_t val));
};


TEST(unit_test, Alfa_test) {
    MockMan mock;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, set(1));

    EXPECT_EQ(alfa(true), true);
}
```

I simplified the code a lot :)
What is the problem? Mock is not called, instead I always get original method 'set' called and aaa printed.

Comment: You would need `bool alfa(Man& m, bool a)` to allow mocking.

Comment: Is it only possible solution? cuz this is rather unacceptable :/

Comment: yes, why is it unacceptable?

Comment: For such solution I would need to 

#include <Man.h>
to alfa.h and 
alfa.h is included furhter to some c code.

Man.h constains for example
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

which do not compile in c code

Comment: Your SystemUnderTest (`bool alfa(bool)` in your case) must have a [dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to `Man`; One possible approach: `bool alfa(std::shared_ptr<IMan> man, bool)`;